# Close/hide a div only when the inputs are complete, without a submit button

Tags: javascript, html

How do I **close/hide a div** ONLY

> after the input fields have been filled out.

I would like to use `JavaScript` to complete the `hide/close` without a submit button.(I do not know how to) So once the input field is completed there is a few second delay before the div hides/closes.

```
<div id="hide">
<label> Type your name </label>
<input type="text" name="personal"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use onBlur() on textbox

Comment: Add ids to your inputs and then access them in your event function using `document.getElementById("<input_id>")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3665he3h/2/)

```
<div id="hide">
  <label> Type your name </label>
  <input type="text" name="personal" onblur="myFunction()" />
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(hidemydiv, 1000); //executes the function hidemydiv in 1000 miliseconds
  }

  function hidemydiv() {
    document.getElementById("hide").style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: would this work for multiple inputs ? Maybe if i classed all the inputs the same name?

Comment: Yes, it will work for multiple inputs as long as they are in the same div. Check the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3665he3h/3/

Comment: Sorry to annoy, but  what if there are 3 radio buttons how would you modify it to detect if a radio button is selected?

Comment: You'll have to use `if(document.getElementById(<RADIO_BUTTON_ID>).checked) {
  //radio button is checked
}`

Comment: @Jack Youitt please mark this as an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#txtbx").keyup(function(){

setTimeout(function ()
{
$("#hide").hide();
},3000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide">
<label> Type your name </label>
<input type="text" name="personal" id="txtbx"/>
</div>
```

Hope!!! it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

It will help you! Try this!!!

```js
$("#txtbx").keyup(function()
{ 
 setTimeout(go,2000);
 
});

function go()
{
 $("#hide").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide">
<label> Type your name </label>
<input type="text" name="personal" id="txtbx"/>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants to do this in Javascript, not in Jquery.

Comment: Jquery is JavaScript.

Comment: Correct but use cases might be different

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() for solving the problem.

```js
var myVar;
var textChange = function(e) {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="hide">
<label> Type your name </label>
<input type="text" name="personal" onchange="textChange()"/>
</div>
```

Hope it is what you are looking for

Comment: what if there are multiple input fields though?

Comment: @Chris No, it will not invoke the function immediately. check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: @JackYouitt well this should not be your case, you should avoid doing this on multiple fields. Submit buttons are meant for these kind of situation.What you can do is to put this function on the last field just before the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".focusout()"  on input box for show / hide the div.